# Self-regulated stepwise evolution

Tags: soft-question, data

Are there empirical examples of self-regulated punctuated evolution (with time)?

This is when a quantity grows over time in a stepwise fashion, with each growth step having less amplitude than the previous one, eventually reaching an asymptote:

[image]

A simple question yet I can't find any examples that can illustrate such a process. I found many experiments that show such a punctuated evolution but they have an exogeneous (human) control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The growth of a tree, each year grow a little, in winter rest, reached top of the canopy stops growing.

A measure of the efficiency of metabolic systems during natural evolution (Jumps: new chemical pathways; limit:100%).

Elevation of a mountain chain (steps: landslides/earthquakes; limit: flatlands)

Liquid saturation of a sponge (steps: new pores invaded;  limit: full saturation)

(similar to previous) 
Magnetization of a piece of steel (steps: new magnetic domain aligned; limit: equilibrium/saturation)